# Objective c + Tesseract issue

Tags: objective-c, text, uiimage, tesseract

I've simple code that performs recognition text on image as below:

```
#import "ParseLinesFromImage.h"
#import <TesseractOCR/TesseractOCR.h>

@implementation ParseLinesFromImage
- (void) performRecognitionWithImage:(UIImage*)image
{     dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT, 0), ^{
    G8Tesseract* tesseract = [[G8Tesseract alloc] initWithLanguage:@"eng"];
    tesseract.language = @"eng";
    tesseract.engineMode = G8OCREngineModeTesseractCubeCombined;
    tesseract.pageSegmentationMode = G8PageSegmentationModeAuto;
    tesseract.maximumRecognitionTime = 60.0;
```

1. **tesseract.image = [image g8_blackAndWhite];**

   ```
   BOOL recognized = [tesseract recognize];
   if (recognized == YES)
   {
       NSDictionary *array = [self parseValidLines:tesseract.recognizedText];
       dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
           [self.delegate sucessWithText:array];
       });
   }
   else
   {
       dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
           [self.delegate failedTextReader:nil];
       });
   }
   ```

   });
   }

Code define in .h file like below:

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
@protocol ParseLinesFromImageDelegate<NSObject>
@required
-(void) sucess:(nullable NSDictionary*)info;
-(void) failed:(nullable NSError*) error;
@end

@interface ParseLinesFromImage: NSObject
@property (nonatomic, weak, nullable) id <ParseLinesFromImageDelegate>  delegate;
- (void) performRecognitionWithImage:(UIImage* _Nonnull)image;
@end
```

But when running to line marked as 1, system push an exeption 
**"Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[UIImage g8_blackAndWhite]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x60c0000b9e00'"**

In my view it may be an ambiguous between UIImage+G8Filters.h(define g8_blackAndWhite) and UIImage but I look into TesseractOCR example, it's the same as mine. 
Please help me to find out the reason and how to fix it, thanks.

PS: Thanks you for reading my question, after google and follow answer from https://github.com/gali8/Tesseract-OCR-iOS/wiki/Installation (side note), the issue goes away and in my case, I added _all-load to my project.

Comment: Please edit this to use proper Markdown formatting.